# Strange WPF Xaml behaviour - XAML grid element remaining null in Window_Load

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a grid in a XAML file in a WPF project. This MainGrid contains 3 columns into which I have placed another 3 grids.

If I arrange the MainGrid children in order 0,1,2 in the XAML e.g.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Name="grid0"></Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="grid1"></Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column ="2" Name="grid2"></Grid>
```

then the grid2 remains null at runtime (in the MainWindow_Loaded event).

However, if I rearrange the order in the XAML file as below, then everything is not null and it works fine.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="grid1"></Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column="2" Name="grid2"></Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column ="0" Name="grid0"></Grid>
```

Copying the code to a new project cannot reproduce the problem, and so it must be something to do with a setting in my current project. Does anyone have any ideas where I should look to determine what is behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look in the files generated for your *.xaml* files. These are the *.g.cs* files in your *obj* directory. Perhaps comparing the non-working *.g.cs* file to a working one will give you a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Kent - I did take a look but in all cases the object was being instantiated correctly in the g.cs files.

I imagine this is a bug and just wondered if anyone else has come across it. It seems to affect the last declared XAML elements in my case.